# Добавить Vue CDN в сниппет

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, сниппеты

В последнее время достаточно часто попадаются вопросы по Vue, но сниппеты не работают, т. к. новичок не добавляет сам CDN.

React, Angular уже есть, может пора бы и Vue добавить?

Comment: Да ну, толку никакого. Там и реакт несвежий.

Comment: @Qwertiy, Меня немного сильно запарило самому искать ссылку и заменять её, вставив перед этим `script:src` с жуквери. И реакт можно обновить. Связать эти поля с каким-нибудь провайдером CDN, при загрузке проверять новые версии, если есть, значит обновить `select`. Или как-то так.

Comment: @Other Здесь бессмысленно это запрашивать, лучше попытать счастья на главной мете или мете enSO.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, Слывёт молва что и сюда заглядывают разрабы.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, на главной-то зачем?

Comment: @Qwertiy Во-первых, там [такие вопросы есть](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stack-snippets), а значит, — это он-топик. Во-вторых, там часто заглядуют сами разработчики и их начальство, которые что-то могут поменять коренным образом (как и на MSOen).

Comment: @Qwertiy На главной мете было бы вообще это всё корректней рассматривать, чем на любой локальной мете, так как эти изменения затрагивают много разных сообществ.